# Pentaho- Can we import a sub report/ report into a report in Pentaho?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer, pentaho-design-studio

I am having multiple reports which includes same subsections created by sub reports.

I want to make changes in the sub reports in the main reports,
Present approach- Open each report and modify the sub report in it.
Expection- Change in one sub report/report and the changes should reflect on all the main reports.

I am looking for a way where we can import the same sub report on multiple reports

Answer (score 0):

From your question, what i understood is that you want to copy a sub-report to any other report:-

**Answer:**
At first you need to open all necessary report in the same report designer. Then you can copy any sub report and paste in your any desire/main report.